# Can I inject a wrapper div with knockout.js bindings foreach

Tags: knockout.js

```
<div id="metro-scrollbar" data-bind="foreach: data.sections , visible: data.sections.length > 0">
    <section data-bind="foreach: $data.tiles, visible: $data.tiles.length > 0, css: { 'last' : $parent.isLastSection($index)}">
        <div data-bind="attr : {'class' : $root.getClass($data,$parentContext.$index,$index)} ">

            <div data-bind="attr : {'class' : $root.getAspectClass($data,$index)} "></div>
            <div class="live-tile">
                <span class="tile-title" data-bind="text: title, css:{'big' : bigtitle}"></span>
                <div>
                    <p>a</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I have the above binding. I need to in some casses to inject a wrapper around the inner divs.

```
<div>
    <section>
        <-- if $myFunction() inject <div> -->
        <div>
            <div></div> // THIS IN HERE SHOULD BE THERE ALWAYS:
            <div >      // THIS IN HERE SHOULD BE THERE ALWAYS:
            </div>      // THIS IN HERE SHOULD BE THERE ALWAYS:
        </div>
         <-- if $myFunction() inject </div> -->
    </section>
</div>
```

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: If its possible, creating a template for the inner divs, and a template for the injected div. The template for the injected div should then call the template for the innerdivs. Then based on myFunction either of the two templates are used. Possible?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  So what you're trying to do is add some element wrapping the children of the `section` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

s093294 had the right idea. Here's an example of a solution (and a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4dFD/)):

**View**

```
<button data-bind="click: click">Toggle</button>

<section data-bind="template: { name: templateName }"></section>

<script type="text/html" id="outer-tmpl">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'inner-tmpl' }">
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="inner-tmpl">
    <div>first inner div</div>
    <div>second inner div</div>
</script>
```

**Model**

```
viewModel = {
    toggle: new ko.observable(true),
    templateName: function () {
        return viewModel.toggle() ? 'outer-tmpl' : 'inner-tmpl';
    },
    click: function () {
        viewModel.toggle(!viewModel.toggle());
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```